# What is disadvantageous about measuring time events using light signals sent from events?

Tags: special-relativity

In his paper: *[On the electrodynamics of moving
bodies](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf)*, under the section entitled **I. KINEMATICAL PART**: **§ 1. Definition of Simultaneity**, Einstein discusses time and gives it an operational definition. He employs Simultaneity to define the time of an event:

> If, for instance, I say, “That train arrives here at 7 o’clock,” I
>   mean something like this: “The pointing of the small hand of my watch
>   to 7 and the arrival of the train are simultaneous events.”

And then, he goes on to say that such definition is satisfactory, only when we are measuring the time of events that are located at the position of one's clock. It fails with events that are distant away.

To overcome this problem he suggests:

> We might, of course, content ourselves with time values determined by
>   an observer stationed together with the watch at the origin of the
>   co-ordinates, and co-ordinating the corresponding positions of the
>   hands with light signals, given out by every event to be timed, and
>   reaching him through empty space. But this co-ordination has the
>   disadvantage that it is not independent of the standpoint of the
>   observer with the watch or clock, as we know from experience.

What I understand is that, we have a clock that is positioned at the origin, and every time there's an event, a light signal is sent from the point at which the event occurred to the origin, and measuring the spatial separation between the event and dividing it by the speed of light, one can determine the time of that distant event.

He says such a procedure is disadvantageous because '*it is not independent of the
standpoint of the observer with the watch or clock, as we know from experience*'.

So again, to overcome this problem of dependency of the standpoint of the observer with the clock, In the next paragraphs, he proposes [The Einstein-Poincaré synchronisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation).

My questions: -I don't understand what he means by: '*it is not independent of the
standpoint of the observer with the watch or clock, as we know from experience*'?.

It seems to me that it's an effective method for measuring time events, and it depends on sending light signals just like The Einstein-Poincaré synchronisation does, with the only difference between the two methods is that the former has only one clock at the origin, while the latter has clocks that are located at every position in space, and they both seem to work perfectly fine.

So what is disadvantageous then about the former method?

-And How The Einstein-Poincaré synchronisation resolves this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason "*it is not independent of the standpoint of the observer with the watch or clock, as we know from experience,*" is that one clock moving at one speed has just the one clock. One person gets to look at their own clock and everyone else has to defer to them to find out.

But once the group is synchronized then each can look at their own clock. Now each person at rest on that frame can use the same clock. Keep in mind that synchronizing clocks was historically a difficult problem (i.e. the longitude prize).

Here is a similar idea called radar time and radar distance:

You assign a radar time and a radar distance by sending a light signal from the clock to the event and having it bounce back to the clock.

If the signaling left the clock at time $t_A$ then came back at time $t_B$ then it traveled  $(t_B-t_A)c$ roundtrip so you can say the radar distance is $(t_B-t_A)c/2.$  And the radar time is not exactly like you suggest. Just subtract $(t_B-t_A)/2$ from $t_B$ and get the radar time $(t_B+t_A)/2.$  This is a perfectly fine way assign times to distant events. It is the usually way when spacetime is flat and the clock is moving inertially and clicks at a steady calibrated rate.

It also works when the clock moves in an arbitrarily fashion, works in that it labels events that are not beyond the horizon of the observer. These are just labels.

Now this isn't actually different than the synchronization procedure.  All that happens there is that you put clocks at every location and adjust them so they agree with the radar time of the original clock. And if you are in special relativity then every inertially moving clocks may be so adjusted by simply changing the rate it ticks and an offset. This fact does not generalize to general relativity nor does it generalize to situations where the original clock is not moving inertially.